# IntelliJ Diff Tool in SourceTree

Tags: git, intellij-idea, diff, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to use IntelliJ Diff tool in SourceTree? I know it is accessible from terminal.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Took some time to figure out arguments.
Diff command text box should contain path to intellij, like: `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app/Contents/MacOS/idea`

[image]

Comment: It's similar for WebStorm (tested on Yosemite & latest versions of WS and ST). Diff command: `/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm` Arguments: `diff $LOCAL $PWD/$REMOTE`

Comment: Please be careful with extra empty spaces. Full path is needed, even if the parent dir is on `$PATH`

Comment: you might need to use a launcher script on non.windows systems: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html?origin=old_help

Comment: The accepted answer should be https://stackoverflow.com/a/38587972/4266287

Answer (score 32):

For OSX android studio i've accomplished with this steps:

**Open IntelliJ/Android Studio -> Tools -> Create Command Line Launcher**

[image: Something like this:]

After that, open SourceTree Preferences: and put **"/usr/local/bin/studio"** in Diff/Merge Command.
Like this:

[image: Like This:]

**Diff Arguments:**

```
diff $LOCAL $PWD/$REMOTE
```

**Merge Arguments:**

```
merge $PWD/$LOCAL $PWD/$REMOTE $PWD/$BASE $PWD/$MERGED
```

And if everything it's ok it should work.

Comment: Is it possible to create static launcher for windows? I use EAP version and path of IDE executable changes on every update because one of the folders in path has version in name

Answer (score 13):

**Windows**
Diff Command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.2\bin\idea.exe`
Arguments: `diff $LOCAL $PWD/$REMOTE`

Merge Command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.2\bin\idea.exe`
Arguments: *(This isn't working right for me. I'm having pathing problems.)* `merge $LOCAL $PWD/$REMOTE $PWD/$BASE $MERGED`

---

As of 12.1, these are the arguments for using IntelliJ's diff and merge tools from outside the program:

**Diff tool**
`<path to IntelliJ IDEA launcher> diff <path to file1> <path to file2>`

**Merge tool**
`<path to IntelliJ IDEA launcher> merge <path to file1> <path to file2> <path to file3> <path to output>`

[OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION: running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html)

---

FWIW, I ended up using IntelliJ for my source control. I like it more than Sourcetree. It's quite robust.

Comment: I am using intellij for conflicts and diff, but I use sourcetree for regular stuff.

Comment: I tried to use Intellij as merge tool but I'm getting errors as it doesn't get the correct temporary files created by Source Tree. It's like it doesn't wait Source tree finishes to create the temporaries, Then it gets a wrong number reference.

Answer (score 12):

For today (January 2019) it works at windows like this:

External Diff/Merge:

> Diff tool:

`Diff Command: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2018.3.1\bin\webstorm64.exe`

`Agruments: diff $LOCAL $REMOTE`

> Merge Tool:

`Diff Command:  C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2018.3.1\bin\webstorm64.exe`

`Agruments: merge $LOCAL $REMOTE $BASE $MERGED`

Answer (score 5):

If somebody is interested in **Android Studio** settings in **Mac**:

```
<path to IntelliJ IDEA launcher>:
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

Diff tool
<path to IntelliJ IDEA launcher> diff <path to file1> <path to file2>

Merge tool
<path to IntelliJ IDEA launcher> merge <path to file1> <path to file2> <path to file3> <path to output>
```

The only problem which I notice is that Android Studio cannot show more than 1 diff at once. When I try, it complains that the file cannot be showed

Answer (score 5):

On Mac with intellij 2016

```
diff $LOCAL $PWD/$REMOTE

merge $PWD/$LOCAL $PWD/$REMOTE $PWD/$BASE $PWD/$MERGED
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently discovered a more convenient way to use IntelliJ Diff Tool without any settings at all.

1. Merge two branches in SourceTree
2. In IntelliJ IDE (for me its Webstorm) go "VCS->Git->Resolve Conflicts"

This way works perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the merge-tool on windows, these arguments work for me:

```
merge $PWD/$LOCAL $PWD/$REMOTE $PWD/$MERGED
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PHPStorm 2013 on Windows and Sourcetree >2.4 I had to escape the arguments and add a full path to the merge options.

Diff / Merge command:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.3.6\bin\phpstorm64.exe
```

diff arguments:

```
diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

merge arguments:

```
merge \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\" \"$PWD/$MERGED\"
merge \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\" \"$PWD/$BASE\" \"$PWD/$MERGED\"
```

[Jetbrans docs command line merge](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-merge-tool.html)

Answer (score 0):

On **macOS** with **IntelliJ IDEA CE**.

**Diff Command**: `open`
**Arguments**: `-W -b com.jetbrains.intellij.ce --args diff "$LOCAL" "$PWD/$REMOTE"`

[image]

Where:

- `open`: System command to open files and directories.
- `-W`: Causes `open` to wait until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited.
- `-b com.jetbrains.intellij.ce`: Bundle identifier for the application to use when opening the file.
- `--args`: All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the `argv` parameter to `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Shad mentioned, IntelliJ may not perform a diff/merge in Windows because the temporary files have not yet been created.

A workaround is to create a file `delayed-intellij.bat` as follows:

`ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\bin\idea64.exe" %*`

Then use this file in Sourcetree: `C:\temp\idea64-delayed.bat`, and it will launch the merge tool with a short delay.

Answer (score 0):

Got IntelliJ to work as SourceTree's diff and merge tool with

- macOS 10.14.6
- IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1 (Community Edition)
- SourceTree 3.2.1 (225)

using

Diff Command: `open`
Arguments: `-W -b com.jetbrains.intellij.ce --args diff "$LOCAL" "$PWD/$REMOTE"`

Merge Tool: `open`
Arguments: `-W -b com.jetbrains.intellij.ce --args merge "$PWD/$LOCAL" "$PWD/$REMOTE" "$PWD/$BASE" "$PWD/$MERGED"`

at `SourceTree > Preferences > Diff`.

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEQEV.png for a screenshot.

Hope this helps somebody :-)

Comment: This has been driving me nuts for months. Thank you for the guidance! I've used Jetbrains with Sourcetree successfully for years, but recently couldn't make the old methods work. FWIW, I had to add `-n` option to force a new process, and I'm using the commercial version so my -b string is just `com.jetbrains.intellij`. Now I'm back in business, albeit strangely. The command line script should have worked.

Comment: FWIW, my system config (that applies to the modifications in the previous comment) is:
OSX: 10.13.6
JBToolbox: 1.15.5796
IntelliJ: 2019.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)
SourceTree: 3.2.1 (225)